# Use sort_values ascending for value greater than 100

Tags: python, pandas

My current code is:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['site stock'] >100].head(50)

df2.sort_values(by=['site stock'],ascending = False)
```

Is there a way to put this code in to just one line of output. I'm sure there is just can't figure out the order it needs to go in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain the commands:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['site stock'] > 100].head(50).sort_values(by=['site stock'], ascending = False)
```

For better readibility, you can split on several lines with parentheses:

```
df2 = (df.loc[df['site stock'] > 100]
         .head(50)
         .sort_values(by=['site stock'], ascending = False)
      )
```

It also makes it easy to quickly comment a line if needed to test something:

```
df2 = (df.loc[df['site stock'] > 100]
         #.head(50)
         .sort_values(by=['site stock'], ascending = False)
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain both lines together with dot:

```
out = df.loc[df['site stock']>100].head(50).sort_values(by=['site stock'],ascending = False)
```

Comment: How would you combine 2 filtered conditions in this instance?
Stuck on this:

df2 = df.loc[df['site stock'] > 100 & df.loc[df['on order'] >0]
            .head(50)
            .sort_values(by=[site stock'], ascending = false)

Comment: @Samgrill - use `df.loc[(df['site stock'] > 100) & (df['on order'] >0)].head(50).sort_values(by=['site stock'], ascending = False)`. Btw, only one answer should be accepted, not both.

Comment: Ah got you, so you're basically putting brackets around both conditions, so that they are picked up as one input within the df.loc.

Sorry will do, I'm learning!